# remove last character of string

Tags: php, string

I have a function that reads my tags from wordpress and prints them out,

```
$posttags = get_the_tags(); 
    if($posttags) {
      foreach($posttags as $tag) {
      echo $tag->name . ',';   
    }  
}
```

Now the function gives me a print that looks like this

Tag1,Tag2,Tag3,

So I tried to use the `mb_substring` function to remove the last ,

```
     $comma = ","; 

$posttags = get_the_tags();  
    if ($posttags) {   
        foreach($posttags as $tag) {   
        echo $tag->name .  mb_substr($comma,0, -1) ;   
    }  
}
```

The problem is that now instead of removing the last comma the print gets like this
TagTagTag

Any ideas how to manipulate the script so only the last comma gets removed?

Answer (score 5):

Do it properly and you won't need extra steps.  How about:

```
$posttags = implode(',', get_the_tags());
```

Or:

```
if($posttags = get_the_tags()) {
    $posttags = implode(',', $posttags);
}
```

Comment: Actually the proper way according to WordPress std is to use [`the_tags()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_tags)

Comment: @onetrickpony:  cool.  I'm not wp guy so don't know the funcs.

Comment: No wonder I don't use wp, `get_the_tags()` returns an array and `the_tags()` returns a comma separated string!  Outstanding!

Comment: It doesn't return it, it outputs the string directly. If you think this is bad, check out `the_terms()` / `get_the_terms()` and `get_terms()` :)

Answer (score 3):

Use `rtrim()`:

```
$no_last_comma = rtrim($string_with_commas, ',');
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not use substr() to remove last character?

$no_last_comma = substr($string_with_commas, 0, -1);